# Tracing second generation java app engine

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, stackdriver, opencensus

i'm trying to get some custom tracing and Firestore tracing added to a second generation app engine java app.

Out of the box i can already see my WebServlets being called and calls to the tasks client library in my cloud console.

But adding new traces is not working and also i see no traces about firestore.

I tried adding new traces as according to the [google](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/setup/java) and [opencencus](https://opencensus.io/integrations/google_cloud/google_cloud_spanner/java/) documentation

```java
try (Scope scope = tracer.spanBuilder("myTrace").startScopedSpan()) {
  // do some http requests
}
```

When i register `StackdriverTraceExporter.createAndRegister()` i get a error message which tells me that it is already configured. Which makes sense as i already see the jetty HttpServlet traces. But i cannot find my own traces.

Also when i check [firestore client library source](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-firestore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/firestore/FirestoreImpl.java) It is also adding traces as expected but they do not appear in the cloud console.

Anyone a idea what i am missing or where to get help?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that OpenCensus on App Engine is [documented](https://opencensus.io/integrations/google_cloud/google_cloud_appengine_standard/) as not supported. However, it does work in the cases that I have tried.

I tried doing tracing from App Engine Standard Java 8 with OpenCensus and was able to get it to work without error. The test app that I tried as based on the [Quickstart for Java 8 for App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/quickstart) with tracing based on the [OpenCensus Tracing Quickstart](https://opencensus.io/quickstart/java/tracing/) and [Stackdriver Export](https://opencensus.io/exporters/supported-exporters/java/stackdriver-trace/) library. The problem that you hit may be related to use of the Firestore and Spanner libraries, which I did not try. Spanner and many other GCP API libraries have built-in instrumentation with OpenCensus but that should not stop you from adding your own tracing as well. I also tried with Datastore using the App Engine Datastore client library. It ran without error but I found that there were no spans generated for the Datastore calls.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.appengine.java8;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

import io.opencensus.common.Scope;
import io.opencensus.exporter.trace.stackdriver.StackdriverTraceConfiguration;
import io.opencensus.exporter.trace.stackdriver.StackdriverTraceExporter;
import io.opencensus.trace.AttributeValue;
import io.opencensus.trace.Span;
import io.opencensus.trace.Status;
import io.opencensus.trace.Tracing;
import io.opencensus.trace.Tracer;
import io.opencensus.trace.config.TraceConfig;
import io.opencensus.trace.config.TraceParams;
import io.opencensus.trace.samplers.Samplers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "OCAppEngineTest", value = "/main")
public class OCAppEngineTest extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
    Tracing.getExportComponent().shutdown();
  }

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws IOException {
    Tracer tracer = Tracing.getTracer();
    try (Scope scope = tracer.spanBuilder("main").startScopedSpan()) {
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
      response.getWriter().println("Hello App Engine - Standard using "
            + SystemProperty.version.get() + " Java "
            + properties.get("java.specification.version"));
    }
  }

  public static String getInfo() {
    return "Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version")
          + " OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name")
          + " User: " + System.getProperty("user.name");
  }

  @Override
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    try {
      setupOpenCensusAndStackdriverExporter();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // log message
    }
  }

  private void setupOpenCensusAndStackdriverExporter()
      throws IOException {
    String appId = SystemProperty.applicationId.get();

    StackdriverTraceExporter.createAndRegister(
      StackdriverTraceConfiguration.builder()
        .setProjectId(appId)
        .build());
    TraceConfig traceConfig = Tracing.getTraceConfig();
    TraceParams activeTraceParams = traceConfig.getActiveTraceParams();
    traceConfig.updateActiveTraceParams(
      activeTraceParams.toBuilder().setSampler(
        Samplers.alwaysSample()).build());
  }

}
```

The test app generates traces like this. Note that the trace agent is opencensus-java, which is different to the built-in App Engine Cloud Trace integration.[image]